CMake test compile fails on docker container because of permission issue
I have a gitlab CI pipeline which builds my software in a windows docker container, this worked fine until I added cpr to my project.
In the configure steps of cpr there's a call to check_cxx_source_runs("int main() { return 0; }" THREAD_SANITIZER_AVAILABLE) in cpr/cmake/sanitizer.cmake
At this stage the configure step fails with the following error:
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/Internal/CheckSourceRuns.cmake:93 (try_run):
  The file:
    C:/builds/<project>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ito77w/Debug/cmTC_4dfe8.exe
  could not be removed:
    Access is denied.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CheckCXXSourceRuns.cmake:52 (cmake_check_source_runs)
  build/_deps/cpr-src/cmake/sanitizer.cmake:13 (check_cxx_source_runs)
  build/_deps/cpr-src/CMakeLists.txt:55 (include)

My understanding is that the compiler was able to generate the test executable but then it tries to cleanup and is unable to delete the file it created.
What I tried so far:

Checking the user in the CI pipeline: echo "$(whoami)" -> user manager\containeradministrator
Setting CMake flags to avoid compiler checks CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS=1, CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS=1
Changing the test target to a static library CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE=STATIC_LIBRARY
Deleting gitlab runner cache

I'm starting to go down a rabbit hole in which I don't feel comfortable because I have very little experience of Docker and Windows permission system so if anyone has an idea I'll gladly take it before I break everything :)

The command check_cxx_source_runs tries to compile code and run resulted executable. Probably, "Access denied" means that the executable is running at that time. E.g. because of an antivirus or so.

I was able to fix this by adding --debug-trycompile to cmake arguments which has the side effect of not deleting the TryCompile/* directories.
